# Como deve ser feito o preenchimento dinâmico do gênero de determinada peça de roupa?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com um "dilema" ao cadastrar um produto, pois **nem todas as opções de roupa são para qualquer gênero**, por exemplo a opção `Saia` e `Vestido` não podem ser do gênero `M (Masculino)`, apenas para o gênero `F (Feminino)`.

O que eu gostaria que fosse feito:

- Ao escolher a opção `Saia` ou `Vestido` no campo `Roupa`, o campo `Gênero` abaixo fosse automaticamente preenchido para a **`<option>`** `F`.
- Quando um item for uma `Camiseta`,  `Calça`, `Bermuda` ou uma `Jaqueta` (pode ser tanto para `M` e `F`), o `<option>` sempre permanecesse a primeira opção do **`<select>`** (nulo).

Como deve ser feito esse tipo de comportamento?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Cadastrar produto </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <p> Roupa:
            <select name="nome" id="nome" required="">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Camiseta">Camiseta</option>
                <option value="Calça">Calça</option>
                <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
                <option value="Jaqueta">Jaqueta</option>
                <option value="Saia">Saia</option>
                <option value="Vestido">Vestido</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p> Gênero: 
            <select name="genero" id="genero" required="">
                <option value=""> </option>
                <option value="M">M</option>
                <option value="F">F</option>    
            </select>
        </p>
        <p> <input type="submit" name="Inserir" value="Cadastrar produto"> </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: faça uma função vinculado ao evento "change" do select "nome", e baseado no valor seta corretamente o valor de genero

Comment: Pode ter algum item só para homem?

Comment: Acho que não precisa, apenas para mulheres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teria que incluir mais uma informação nos options de "Roupa" para saber se a opção escolhida atende apenas mulher, porque o programa não tem como saber que "saia", por exemplo, é só para mulher. Você pode colocar um atributo `data-f` vazio para diferenciar os options só femininos dos demais:

```
<option data-f value="Saia">Saia</option>
```

No evento change você irá verificar se o option selecionado possui `data-f` e alterar o segundo select para F. Se não tiver o atributo, seleciona o primeiro option que tem value vazio:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   document.getElementById("nome").addEventListener("change", function(){
      document.getElementById("genero").value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset.f !== undefined ? "F" : "";
   });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <p> Roupa:
      <select name="nome" id="nome" required="">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="Camiseta">Camiseta</option>
          <option value="Calça">Calça</option>
          <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
          <option value="Jaqueta">Jaqueta</option>
          <option data-f value="Saia">Saia</option>
          <option data-f value="Vestido">Vestido</option>
      </select>
  </p>
  <p> Gênero: 
      <select name="genero" id="genero" required="">
          <option value=""> </option>
          <option value="M">M</option>
          <option value="F">F</option>    
      </select>
  </p>
  <p> <input type="submit" name="Inserir" value="Cadastrar produto"> </p>
</form>
```

Comment: No script você não teria que colocar ele todo dentro de uma function e chama-lo no select do campo roupa? Quando eu faço o teste não está funcionando.

Comment: Não precisa chamar no select. O AddEventListener já escuta quando o select é alterado.

Comment: No meu não tá indo

Comment: Eu coloquei o JS dentro do ```<head>```.

Comment: Atualizei o código JS na resposta. Altera aí que vai funcionar.

Comment: Agora sim, o JS está funcionando, obrigado ai cara.